# How to avoid creating an excess of agents when reading their characteristics from a CSV file

Tags: csv, netlogo, consumer, agent-based-modeling

I have data related to 100 consumers as turtles who have rated laptops' features. The laptops have 2 kinds of features : size of the screen and battery life. Each has some levels. For example battery life has 5 hours, 12 hours, 24 hours, 30 hours. Data is stored in a csv file. For simplicity, here you see 2 consumers.

```
   size12  size13.5  size14  size15  Battery5  Battery12 Battery24 Battery30 
1  1        *2*         1      3        2         2           *4*       5
2  4        3           3      2        1          1           2        3
```

We access the data set to sum the rates of 2 levels of feature. For example for consumer 1 , what is:

```
The sum of rates of screen size of 13.5 + rate of battery life 24
```

Using the code below, this is achieved :

```
to CalculateSumRates
  ca
  reset-ticks
  file-close-all
  file-open "turtle_details.csv"
  let headings csv:from-row file-read-line
  set screen-headings sublist headings 0 4
  set battery-headings sublist headings 4 length headings

  let screen-to-evaluate 13.5
  let battery-to-evaluate 24

  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let data csv:from-row file-read-line
    create-turtles 1 [
      set turtle-screen-list sublist data 0 4
      set turtle-battery-list sublist data 4 length data
      set turtle-screen-eval turtle-screen-rating screen-to-evaluate
      set turtle-bat-eval turtle-battery-rating battery-to-evaluate
      set turtle-sum-eval turtle-screen-eval + turtle-bat-eval
    ]
  ]
  file-close-all

end

to-report turtle-screen-rating [sc]
  let pos position sc screen-headings
  let turt-screen-rate-value item pos turtle-screen-list
  report turt-screen-rate-value
end

to-report turtle-battery-rating [bc]
  let pos position bc battery-headings
  let turt-bat-rate-value item pos turtle-battery-list
  report turt-bat-rate-value
end
```

Now I want to do something more. I need to consider a time interval. For example, in 20 years, how consumers change their ratings of some laptop features. To illustrate more, consumer 1 who has expressed her total ranking of size 13.5 and battery of 24, in year 2 (ticks = 2) got her laptop improved, so now we would like to know :

```
The sum of rates of screen size of 13.5 + rate of battery life **30**
```

I first created my `go` like this :

```
 to setup
      CalculateSumRates
    end


to go
repeat 20 [

   { screen-to-evaluate changes and is no longer 13.5}
   { battery-to-evaluate also changes and is no longer 24}
```

; **EDIT**

```
set turtle-screen-eval turtle-screen-rating screen-to-evaluate
  set turtle-bat-eval turtle-battery-rating battery-to-evaluate
  set turtle-sum-eval turtle-screen-eval + turtle-bat-eval
```

; **EDIT**

```
  tick
]
end
```

What is making trouble here is that, each time `CalculateSumRates` is called, it goes to this line :

```
 create-turtles 1 [
```

So every year, 100 consumers are created from scratch while I need to monitor the behvavior of those 100 consumers at the beginning.

I then wrote 2 `CalculateSumRates` functions, called one in the set up. Renamed the function and put the other in the go. In order not to create an excess of consumers, I substituted `create-turtles 1 [` with `ask consumers [`, hoping that now the csv is again read, but row by row is read when I say ask consumers, so I can find different values from the dataset. However, it is executing weirdly.  I do not know how to modify that to avoid creating new consumers and losing the previous ones?

By adding the lines in the edit, I encounter an error telling me that I cannot use go in an observer context; go is turtle only!!
Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the code to `CalculateSumRate`? Also, are the consumers the same from year to year, or different? That is, do the consumers in the first dataset match up with the consumers in future datasets? How are the future datasets stored? Just separate CSV files?

Comment: Thanks. Consumers are the same from year to year. I also have only one data set which is going to be used every year. The data set is the same, but each year, for each consumer,  different columns would be read. For example, in year 1, for consumer 1 , i need to know what are the rate of screen size 13 and battery of 24, but next year, I need to access another level like screen size of 13.5 and battery of 30. The code for 'CalculateSumRate' is up there. But these lines ' let screen-to-evaluate 13.5
  let battery-to-evaluate 24'  will be different as time passes.

Comment: I think I understand a bit better now. The reason I suggested you use the approach in my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832066/using-to-reports-while-creating-agents-from-a-csv-file/44835405?noredirect=1#comment77158359_44835405), where each turtle stores its potential values, is that you can then access that turtle's value for any combination of screen/battery life. You *shouldn't* go back to the csv at all- there's no need, since the turtle has a list of ratings that, importantly, you can update as needed (if they change their screen rating, for example).

Comment: Thanks so much. I could imagine that I can access any combination by your approach, but had some difficulties making it happen. I edited my question by adding what is causing the problem as edits.

Comment: Sorry I just saw that after I had written out an answer- have a look in there and see if it might explain the error you were getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give an example of what I meant in the comment above, check out this modified version of the setup that I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832066/using-to-reports-while-creating-agents-from-a-csv-file/44835405?noredirect=1#comment77158359_44835405).

```
extensions [ csv ]

globals [ screen-headings battery-headings ]

turtles-own [
  turtle-screen-list
  turtle-battery-list
  turtle-screen-eval
  turtle-bat-eval
  turtle-sum-eval
  turtle-row-number
  ;; New:
  rating-each-year 
]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  file-close-all
  file-open "turtle_details.csv"
  let headings csv:from-row file-read-line
  set screen-headings sublist headings 0 4
  set battery-headings sublist headings 4 length headings

  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let data csv:from-row file-read-line
    create-turtles 1 [
      set turtle-screen-list sublist data 0 4
      set turtle-battery-list sublist data 4 length data
      set rating-each-year []

    ]
  ]

  file-close-all

  ask turtles [
    update-vals 12 5
    set rating-each-year lput turtle-sum-eval rating-each-year
  ]

end
```

It's more or less the same, but there are some important changes like a new list called `rating-each-year` that is intended to let the turtles keep track of their rating each tick.

The reporters are mostly unchanged as well, except that `update-vals` is now a turtle-specific procedure so it must be called by `ask turtles` (or similar). Additionally, it takes two variables, one called `screen?` and one called `battery?`. You can then call the reporter by asking a turtle to: `update-vals 12 24`, and that turtle will then update its values for a screen size of 12 and a battery life of 24. I include all three reporters for completeness, but the other two have not changed from my answer to your other question:

```
to update-vals [ screen? battery? ]
    set turtle-screen-eval turtle-screen-rating screen?
    set turtle-bat-eval turtle-battery-rating battery?
    set turtle-sum-eval turtle-screen-eval + turtle-bat-eval
end

to-report turtle-screen-rating [sc]
  let pos position sc screen-headings
  let turt-screen-rate-value item pos turtle-screen-list
  report turt-screen-rate-value
end

to-report turtle-battery-rating [bc]
  let pos position bc battery-headings
  let turt-bat-rate-value item pos turtle-battery-list
  report turt-bat-rate-value
end
```

So now, your turtles can at any time update their summed rating value according to the screen and battery combination that you have assigned them or that they have bought, however you are setting that up. Here is an example `go` procedure that every tick has them choose a random possible screen size and battery life to evaluate, then they add that summed rating value to their `rating-each-year` list. When 20 ticks go by, the procedure stops and the turtles show their lists in the command center (21 items long, since they include the value from `setup` as well).

```
to go
  ifelse ticks < 20 [
    ask turtles [
      let screen-this-year one-of screen-headings
      let battery-this-year one-of battery-headings
      update-vals screen-this-year battery-this-year
      set rating-each-year lput turtle-sum-eval rating-each-year
    ]
  ]
  [
    ask turtles [
      show rating-each-year
    ]
    stop
  ]
  tick 
end
```

In your model, you probably wouldn't have them randomly pick values of course- this was more to show what they're actually doing. I should also mention that "turtle_details.csv" is the same as the one I used for an example in the last question.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me ask some questions to hopefully understand your solution. Why did you add ` set turtle-battery-list fput item 0 data turtle-battery-list` ?

Comment: Great question- the answer is... by accident. It was a holdover from when we had discussed having the turtles know the row number from which their ratings values had been pulled. I have modified the setup procedure slightly- see if that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks. I just remembered that you had mentioned it before when I asked what if I want to keep the row number column for the second sublist as well. I do not need that now though, so the current set up is of more help than the previous one to what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yep, that sounds right. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks so much Luke. I could eventually get how to use your awesome suggestion, and it looks great.

Comment: That error saying that I couldnot use `go` in an observer context; `go` is `turtle` only. I noticed a procedure in `go` was just dealing with consumers' variables, so I did not add `ask consumers` inside the procedure. I just modified go :
`to go `
`ask consumers`[
     `access-data-set]`
and it seems working.

Comment: Right on, happy to help and I'm glad you sorted it out!