# Netlogo - item expected input to be a string but got zero instead

Tags: csv, netlogo

This is a follow-up question related to a previous post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832066/using-to-reports-while-creating-agents-from-a-csv-file)I have data related to 16 laptop consumers' review ratings which are either satisfied (16 people) or dissatisfied (6 people). They are defined as turtles and they are distinguishable by asking if the boolean variable satisfied? or dissatisfied? is true. 
[image]

The dataset is read as follows:

```
extensions [csv matrix array nw]

globals
[
  rowcounter
  csv 


 ii
  Sc-headings Bat-headings Pr-headings income-headings  average-headings; 

  Sc-set 
  Bat-set 
  Pr-set 

  prodcount ;num of producer agents

]

turtles-own [    
  turtle-Sc-list
  turtle-Bat-list
  turtle-Pr-list
  turtle-income-list
  turtle-average-list

  review-set 

  satisfied?
  dissatisfied?

  LapUtl-set 

  ScPWU
  BatPWU
  PrPWU
]

to setup
  clear-all
  file-close-all

  set rowcounter 1
  proddata
  readdataset
 reset-ticks
end

breed [ producers producer ]
to go

        Reviewrating
    end
to intlz
  set Sc-set []
  set Bat-set []
  set Pr-set []

end
```

Reading the dataset:

```
to readdataset
  file-close-all ; close all open files
  file-open "turtle_details.csv"
  let headings csv:from-row file-read-line           ;header is read
  ; Splitting headings of the csv file into 5 categories representing screen 
  ; size data, battery charge data, Price data, income data, max age of an owner

  set Sc-headings sublist headings 2 7   
  set Bat-headings sublist headings 7 12
  set Pr-headings sublist headings 12 17
  set income-headings sublist headings 17 18
  set average-headings sublist headings 18 length headings

  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
  let data csv:from-row file-read-line

  create-turtles 1 [

       set shape "person"
       set size 2.5
       ifelse rowcounter <  11
      [
       set color 125
       set satisfied? true  
       set dissatisfied? false                                        ;                       
  ]
     ;else
      [
        set color 65

        set satisfied? false 
       set dissatisfied? true                                           ;                       
  ]


       setxy random-xcor random-ycor
       ; hide-turtle


       set turtle-Sc-list sublist data 2 7 
       set turtle-Bat-list sublist data 7 12
       set turtle-Pr-list sublist data 12 17

       set turtle-income-list sublist data 17 18
       set turtle-averageage-list sublist data 18 length data


  ]
  set rowcounter rowcounter + 1
   ]

  file-close-all
end
```

There are 3 producers who have some attribute levels for the screen, battery, price.

```
Sc  Bat Pr
24  10  18000
18  6   22000
30  8   26000

to proddata
  file-close-all ; close all open files

  if not file-exists? "Prodinitattr.csv" [
    user-message "No file 'Prodinitattr.csv' exists!"
    stop
  ]
  file-open "Prodinitattr.csv" ; open the file with the producers' initial attributes
  let headings csv:from-row file-read-line

  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
       let data csv:from-row file-read-line
       create-producers 1 [
       hide-turtle
       set producer? true   ; this agent is a producer
       set satisfied? false   ; this agent is not a referrer                                             ;                       REFERRERS
       set dissatisfied? false     ; this agent is not a pbuyer
       set prodcount prodcount + 1
     ;  set shape "house"
       setxy random-xcor random-ycor
       ]


       set Sc-set lput item 0 data Sc-set            
       set Bat-set lput item 1 data Bat-set
       set Pr-set lput item 2 data Pr-set


  ]
  file-close-all
end
```

The thing that should be extracted from the data set is the evaluation of consumers (reviews). Each consumer has a review-set which is at first an empty set ,[].Then it will keep thee values which corresponds to the three review values for each of the three producers.

```
to reviewrating

ask turtles   [

          set review-set []
     ]

 ask turtles [

          set ii 0
          while [ii < 3 ][
             set ScPWU turtle-Sc-rating item ii Sc-set
             set BatPWU turtle-Bat-rating item ii Bat-set
             set PrPWU turtle-Pr-rating item ii Pr-set


             set LapUtl-set lput (ScPWU  + BatPWU + PrPWU) LapUtl-set

             set ii ii + 1


        ] ; while

      ];ask

end
    to-report turtle-Sc-rating [Sc]

      let pos position Sc Sc-headings

      if  is-number? position Sc Sc-headings
          [
           let turt-Sc-rate-value item pos turtle-Sc-list
            report turt-Sc-rate-value
          ]

    end

    to-report turtle-Bat-rating [Bat]
      let pos position Bat Bat-headings
      if  is-number? position Bat Bat-headings
          [
           let turt-Bat-rate-value item pos turtle-Bat-list
            report turt-Bat-rate-value
          ]

        ;***************

    end
    to-report turtle-Pr-rating [Pr]
      let pos position Pr Pr-headings
      if is-number? position Pr Pr-headings
          [
           let turt-Pr-rate-value item pos turtle-Pr-list
            report turt-Pr-rate-value
          ]

    end
```

The problem is I  cannot see consumers' LapUtl vector because of the error. I had reported another error previously here, but I changed where the "go" procedure was written, and now the error is marking this line :

```
let turt-Sc-rate-value **item** pos turtle-Sc-list
```

How can I resolve tihs?

Thank you,

Comment: what does the error say? You mentioned that you used to get a different error, which is what I assume the title is, but what is the error you get now?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The previous error was fixed by moving the "go" procedure up and having it after the setup. It was about the order of procedures. Now the error says what I have in the title of my question`" item expected input to be a string but got zero instead
". `

Comment: Wihtout the file or other things necessary to actually run this, it's hard to see what's going on. And I'm not clear how the `LapUtl` vector relates to your error since it doesn't appear to be used in the relevant procedure. I would suggest you do some basic debugging with print statements. In your turtle-Sc-rating procedure, do some print statements (eg `print Sc`, `print pos`) to make sure the variable contents are what you expect. If that doesn't help you solve it yourself, try to just give us the problem procedure, the procedure that calls it, and some values for the variables.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are not correctly reporting the error.  I suspect the error is `ERROR: ITEM expected this input to be a string or list, but got a number instead`.  Here is an example of a way to produce this error: `item 0 0`.  If I am right, then you are running the code `let turt-Sc-rate-value item pos turtle-Sc-list` while `turtle-Sc-list` has a value of `0`.  In order to confirm this, replace this code with

```
ifelse (is-list? turtle-Sc-list)
  [let turt-Sc-rate-value item pos turtle-Sc-list]
  [error (word "turtle-Sc-list is not a list.")]
```

Now run your code.  If it raises the error `"turtle-Sc-list is not a list."`, then you are ready to search for how you failed to initialize this variable correctly.